# How to do multiline search and replace with a script?

Tags: linux, sed, multiline, non-greedy

I'm trying to replace every multiline import inside a Python source file.. So, the source goes like

```
from XXX import (
   AAA,
   BBB,
)
from YYY import (
   CCC,
   DDD,
   EEE,
   ...
)
...other instructions...
```

and I'd like to get something like

```
from XXX import AAA, BBB
from YYY import CCC, DDD, EEE, ...
...other instructions...
```

I tried to use sed but it looks like it doesn't support non-greedy matching of the closing parenthesis, so it "eats" the second import.. :(
Any hint? Is this impossible with sed? Should I try with another tool?

Comment: is there always 2 tokens after the 'import' or are they variable?

Comment: I was wondering if this could be done via a single reg-ex :)

Comment: They are variable.. Sorry, I'll clarify the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ummm... what's wrong with Python?

```
lineIter= iter(aFile)
for aLine in lineIter:
    if aLine.startswith("import"):
        if aLine.endswith("("):
            for aModule in lineIter:
                if aModule.endwith(")"):
                    break
                print "import", aModule.strip()
        else:
            print aLine.stri()
    else:
        print aLine.strip()
```

Comment: Not every system has it installed? A lot of the machines I work on certainly don't.

Comment: Bryan, since he wants to modify a python source file, bets are that he has access to some machine with python installed :)

Comment: Python is perfectly fine :) I was trying with sed because it looked like the right tool for the task :)

Comment: @Joril: sed's hard to use (as you've noted).  Therefore, it isn't really the right tool for task, is it?

Comment: Well, it would have been if it had support for non-greedy matching :) But I didn't know it X-)

Comment: @Joril: I disagree -- if the non-greedy matching isn't obvious, it's too hard to use.  And, for most tasks like this, it doesn't really add any value to mash the process down to a few cryptic lines of incomprehensible sed.

Comment: I see your point.. sed expressions are often somewhat "write-only" :D But I still find it very handy for small tasks (not like this one of course). Thanks for sharing your thoughts! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366980/what-are-the-differences-between-perl-python-awk-and-sed#367082 -- can't see the value in sed.  Used to use sed.  Gave it up because Python seemed to always be better.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^from/,/^)/{H;//{x;/)/{s/[\n()]//g;s/  */ /g;s/,$//;p;x}};d}' source
from XXX import AAA, BBB
from YYY import CCC, DDD, EEE, ...
...other instructions...
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here is a somewhat polished version of S.Lott's script (I'd have posted it as a comment, but it's too long ^^; ).. This version preserves indentation and produces a result closer to my example.

```
lineIter=iter(aFile)
for aLine in lineIter:
    s = aLine.strip()
    if s.startswith("from ") and s.endswith("("):
        complete = s[:-1]
        for aModule in lineIter:
            m = aModule.strip()
            if m.endswith(")"):
                break
            complete += m.strip()
        print complete
    else:
        print aLine,
```