# When should i use sed and when should i use awk

Tags: linux, sed, awk

Last few days and before that i ahve been asking questions about `sed` and `awk`.
This happens everytime that when i ask awk question people say to use sed and when i ask sed question people say to use awk.

can anyone give me some examples on where i can use each one.

To me , `awk` was used to presentation and reporting no substitution
and `sed` was used where something needs to replaced.

But still many people gave me examples where substition is done via `awk` with print commnad.

Now i am really confused what are the uses cases of that.

As an example. suppose

I have source code file in C++ and i want to `add` some code before particular pattern.

what should i use `sed` or `awk`. Pattern can span multiple lines as well

Comment: This post may helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366980/what-are-the-differences-between-perl-python-awk-and-sed

Comment: I did read thats about other programming lnaguages as well in which sed , awk gets lost. I just want to now if we have only two options either sed or awk then what to use where

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The link in the comment is quite valuable. I would add some lines from my personal feeling of sed/awk usage.

I emphasis that, many text processing tasks could be done by both sed and awk. The text below are just my personal feeling.

- if I want to do text processing, and write back to the original file without generating temp file, sed would win.
- I like the sed's address, it could shorten the codes a lot. e.g. `3,6{s/a/b/}`, `1~2{s/f/b/}` or `3~5{s/f/b/}`
- if you want to pass the matched parts to an external commands/programs, awk is easier than sed (Gnu sed). If you want to have some fun and give it a try with sed, you could play a game: match a text, and pass parts (\1,\2 etc) to different sed. that is, sed nesting. after 3 times, I am lost... :)
- if the text is somehow "column" based, in 99% case, awk won't let you down.
- I would choose awk if I want to do different text processing on multi-files. e.g, `{001-003}.txt` different substitution requirements.
- awk would be good at join-like processing among multi-files
- if the logic needs some structure like if-else, for loop, while, number calculation etc, I would go with awk. though can sed in many cases do the job as well.
- both sed and awk don't support Perl Regex. That's a pity.
- So basically, I think awk is more flexible and straightforward than sed. If the task is relatively simple or there are well-known magic sed solutions (check http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt there are many magic one-liners), I would go with sed. otherwise I would think awk first.

Both sed and awk are very powerful text processing tools, there are many text processing tools in linux/unix box, comm, cut, join, paste, sort, uniq...  there are many option parameters of them. I am lazy and cannot remember all of them, just those common used ones. But If I know how to work with awk, sed and grep. 90% text processing under linux could be done. If awk, sed and grep cannot do the job, I would turn to a programming language. e.g. python.

well I am not a perl guy.

is there something that I forgot?

my 2cents, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks buddy , i have heard a lot about perl regex , what is that. To me the regex for sed even seems very powerful.