# Which linux tool is best for parsing multiple files simultaneously

Tags: python, linux, perl, sed, awk

I know bit of all `sed`, `awk` , `python` , but not `perl`.

I need to parse around 100s of different files , find patterns , match multiple columns with each other and put in new files.

and i have to do that on regular basis.

I just want to know which tool will be best for that scenario.
based on that i will buy that books and get more advanced knowledge on that subject

Comment: Maybe [What are the differences between Perl, Python, Awk and Sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366980/what-are-the-differences-between-perl-python-awk-and-sed/) will help.  Given that you know Python and not Perl, I'd have to recommend Python to you (unless you're looking for an excuse to learn Perl).

Answer (score 2):

This thread is going to start a war on which is best :)

As you know `python`, you should definitely go with that. I myself have done a lot of text manipulation using python, where everything else tend to become complex.

Even though `awk` can do what you need, you won't like what you see in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Perl is the best language for text manipulation. The task you want to do can be done easily and very fast using Perl.

Start with either "Learning Perl" book or the official documentation "[perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/)". More sources are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info).

And make sure you search [CPAN](http://metacpan.org) to avoid reinventing the same wheel :)

Comment: Sounds a bit subjective to me...

Comment: Well Perl was designed around parsing text. Python may work just as well.

Comment: `based on that i will buy that books and get more advanced knowledge on that subject`. I took it as he's willing to learn new things.